# Uvicorn save whole log in log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging, uvicorn

Does anyone have an idea why my Uvicorn log is not logging the important things like this:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:63695 - "POST /uploadfile2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     127.0.0.1:63699 - "POST /uploadfile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

But it shows some lines of the log - only system Start and System Stop? How to do it correctly, that's my recent code block to setup the log file:

```
        formatter = Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s | %(funcName)-19s | %(message)s')
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(conf_args["logPath"], when="midnight")
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        log = getLogger('log')
        fastapi_logger = getLogger("uvicorn")
        log.addHandler(handler)
        fastapi_logger.addHandler(handler)
        log.setLevel(logging_level)
```

Here I start the script like every noob:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8009)
```